# Have the Google cloud-builder images moved to Artifact Registry?

Tags: google-cloud-build, google-container-registry, google-artifact-registry

Are there updated locations for [Google Cloud Builders](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/gcloud)? Google is encouraging us to move away from the Google Container Registry to the Artifact Registry but the Cloud Builder images are still addressed by eg `gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn:3.5.0-jdk-8` which is a Container Registry address.
I'm in the process of revising all my builds to use Artifact Registry and I would rather not have to make another pas through them to change these `gcr.io/cloud-builders...` references.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Container Registry will still continue to work and will not go away soon. You can still use both services in the same project, that was stated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65731142/16531380) that discusses the differences of Container Registry and Artifact Registry.

There's a guide in [copying images from Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/copy-from-gcr) to Artifact Registry that you can also check in your transition process.

While the official cloud builders aren't hosted yet in Artifact Registry, you have an option to clone the source code and deploy it yourself. Furthermore refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/changes-gcp) for changes in building and deploying in Google Cloud. There's an available guide in [transitioning repositories with gcr.io domain](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/setup-gcr-repo). Just a note, this feature is still on Alpha, and this feature might have limited support. You can further check the previous link for further details in this feature.

Lastly, feel free to submit a [feature request](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/issues/new?assignees=&labels=enhancement%2C+help+wanted&template=feature_request.md&title=%5BFR%5D) on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

While we are planning a future set of Cloud Builders in Artifact Registry, our plan includes keeping the existing set of Container Registry builders in place, and we are specifically *excluding* a forced migration in our planning.

This means that you can migrate your repository use to Artifact Registry while continuing to use the current set of builders in Container Registry in your build steps.

Reference: [Cloud Builders in GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders)

Context: I am an Engineering Manager on the Google Cloud Build team.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud builders are currently hosted on Artifact Registry. They still use gcr.io urls for backwards compatability. Anybody can move to Artifact Registry and keep backwards-compatible gcr.io urls by following these steps: https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/setup-gcr-repo